# Suppressing figures in markdown / quarto documents whilst retaining internal references

Tags: r, graphics, rstudio, quarto

Many journals require authors to submit manuscripts *without* graphics in the manuscript itself. Instead, they want a place holder like this:

**<< @fig-1 ABOUT HERE>>**

The journal format will stipulate that graphics such as figure @fig-1 should be submitted as a separate file, rather than in the manuscript itself.

For authors using markdown this can of course be done manually after knitting to a '*final format*' such as odt, docx, pdf, etc. However, that is not good practice in keeping with the principles of reproducible research.

The present markdown scrpt below is an example of how it can be achieved using R and quarto, whilst retaining the internal automatic figure references and numbering that quarto implements.

Answer (score 0):

---

````
title: "Suppressing graphics"
subtitle: "..as required by some journals"
author: "S. O'Neill"
format: docx
editor: source
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

fig_display = FALSE
tab_display = FALSE

fig_width = ifelse(fig_display, "50%", "0%")
empty_figure <- ggplot() + geom_blank() + theme_void()
```


## Suppressing graphics

Many journals require authors to submit manuscripts _without_ graphics in the manuscript itself. Instead, they want a place holder like this:

**<< @fig-1 ABOUT HERE >>**

The journal format will stipulate that graphics such as figure @fig-1 should be submitted as a separate file, rather than in the manuscript itself.

Sometimes they also want tables in separate files, with an inline place holder:

**<< @tbl-1 ABOUT HERE >>**

For authors using markdown this can of course be done manually after knitting to a '_final format_' such as odt, docx, pdf, etc. However, that is not good practice in keeping with the principles of reproducible research.

The present markdown file is an example of how it can be achieved using R and quarto.

The important bits in this script to note are:

* Check out the chunk in lines 9-11
* Use quarto references to ref figures (see line 18 for example)
* Specify the quarto reference target in a the figure yaml (see line 40)
* In the figure chunk (lines 39-55)
    - In the header (ine 39), set output width to 0%
    - Check out the self-explanatory lines 47-51
    - Remeber to save the actual plot (see line 54) 


## Figures

<!-- , echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, out.width=fig_width} -->
```{r figure1} 
#| echo: false
#| message: false
#| warning: false
#| out.width: !expr fig_width
#| label: fig-1
#| fig-cap: This is an inconsequential figure

# Generate your figure and save to variabel 'p'
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(1000, 0,1)), aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(bins=20)

if (fig_display) {
  p
} else {
  empty_figure
}

# Don't forget to store the actual plot to a separate file
# Can file name be dynamically generated from figure
ggsave("folder/file.png", p, device = "png", width=10, height=10, units="cm", dpi=300)
```

<!-- , echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, out.width=fig_width -->
```{r test_platform}
#| echo: false
#| message: false
#| warning: false
#| out.width: !expr fig_width
#| label: fig-platform
#| fig-cap: Testing and calibration platform used to assess force development during repeated pressure application.

if (fig_display) {
  include_graphics("./gfx/PPT_test_platform_photo.JPG")
} else {
  empty_figure
}

```

```{r table1}
#| echo: false
#| message: false
#| warning: false
#| label: tbl-1
#| tbl-cap: This is a pointless table

df <- data.frame(letters[1:5], 1:5)
names(df)<-c("L","N")
library(kableExtra)
if (tab_display) {
  kable(df)
} else {
  kable(NULL)
}
```
````